# CSV download File Name

Tags: javascript, json, html, csv

I am trying to download a CSV file from json data stored in a variable.

The issue is that I am not able to set the name of the downloaded file.

Here is the code...

```
$('#downloadCSV').click(function () {
    var exportData = 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,';
    exportData += 'nodeid,value\n1,212\n';
    var newWindow = window.open(encodeURI(exportData));
    return false;
});
```

I have already tried to add the HTML5 download attr:

```
<a id="downloadCSV" download="data.csv" href="#">Download CSV</a>
```

I have already tried the solutions provided by others and nothing is working with the current browsers ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) library a really useful cross-browser solution for saving files from JavaScript. Their documentation provides a compatibility table which will show you which browsers support file names.

BTW the `download` attribute on the `<a>` tag is an HTML5 feature which would apply if you were linking to a file's URL directly with the `href`. As you are catching the click event using JavaScript, and then returning false, this will not be doing anything.